# Why is the compiler confused about the levels of indirection in this array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, graphics, windows-phone-8, directx

It seems pretty clear to me so I must be missing something.

Here's the declaration of the array of handles and each individual handle:

```
// and the aggregate handle array for the setbufferscall
ID3D11Buffer * m_constantBuffers[NUM_CONSTANT_BUFFERS];

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_constantMatrixBuffer;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_constantLightBuffer;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_constantMaterialBuffer;
```

And here's what I'm trying to do:

```
// and lastly, we need to aggregate all of these handles into
// one handle array so that it's formatted properly for the
// VSSetConstantBuffers call
m_constantBuffers[0] = m_constantMatrixBuffer.GetAddressOf();
m_constantBuffers[1] = m_constantLightBuffer.GetAddressOf();
m_constantBuffers[2] = m_constantMaterialBuffer.GetAddressOf();
```

Lastly, here's what the compiler is saying:

```
1>Renderer.cpp(66): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'ID3D11Buffer **' to 'ID3D11Buffer *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Renderer.cpp(67): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'ID3D11Buffer **' to 'ID3D11Buffer *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Renderer.cpp(68): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'ID3D11Buffer **' to 'ID3D11Buffer *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

What gives? I thought that dereferencing an array meant that you were dealing with the type that comes before the array declaration, which is ID3D11Buffer * in this case.

Thanks for reading and for any drops of wisdom you can spare

Comment: `GetAddressOf` returns a double pointer, since you use them as a single pointer normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `Get` method, not the `GetAddressOf` method. See [Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230388.aspx) vs [GetAddressOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230388.aspx).